# Сбор ответов с теста с помощью с ajax скрипта

Tags: ajax, html5, html-form

Пытаюсь создать теста, задача которого после прохождения его, все ответы должны приходить на почту. А по завершению теста открывается этаже страница только на ней текст и сбоку форма обратной связи. Как это реализовать? На сайте уже есть одна форма, куда приходят заявки. Пыталась добавить `<form>` каждому вопросу, прописать в php файле и самом скрипте параметры, но толку ноль. Вот сам код.

Скрипт, куда пыталась прописать для обработки.

```js
$("#flip").click(function() {
  $("#panel").show("slow");
});
$(".send").click(function() {
  answercount = $(this).closest(".question").attr("id").split('-')[1];
  console.log(answercount);
  $('#question-' + answercount).addClass('hidden');
  answercount = answercount * 1 + 1;
  console.log(answercount);
  $('#question-' + answercount).toggleClass('hidden');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel">
  <div class="question show" id="question-1" style="display: block;">
    <div class="q-num">Вопрос 1 из 8</div>
    <div class="item-title item-1-title">Что строим?</div>
    <label><input name="sport" type="checkbox">Дом</label><br>
    <label><input name="sport" type="checkbox">Баню</label><br>
    <label><input name="sport" type="checkbox">Малые строения,беседки</label><br>
    <p><input class="send" type="submit" value=Далее></p>
  </div>
  <div class="question hidden" id="question-2" style="display: block;">
    <div class="q-num">Вопрос 2 из 8</div>
    <div class="item-title item-2-title">Укажите площадь</div>
    <label><input name="sport" type="text">m2</label><br>
    <p><input class="send" type="submit" value="Далее"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="question hidden" id="question-3" style="display: block;">
    <div class="q-num">Вопрос 3 из 8</div>
    <div class="item-title item-3-title">Этажность</div>
    <label><input type="checkbox">1 этаж</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">1 этаж+мансарда</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">2 этаж</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">2 этаж+мансарда</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">3 этаж</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">3 этаж+мансарда</label><br>
    <p><input class="send" type="submit" value="Далее"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="question hidden" id="question-4" style="display: block;">
    <div class="q-num">Вопрос 4 из 8</div>
    <div class="item-title item-4-title" style="display: block;">Материал</div>
    <div class="brus">
      <label>
        <img src="bruss.png" style="margin-left: 70px;">
        <br><input type="checkbox">Брус
        <br> Выберите необходимый размер 
        <br><input type="checkbox">100х100мм
        <br> <input type="checkbox">150х150мм
        <br> <input type="checkbox">200х200мм
        <br> <input type="checkbox">200х250мм
</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item-title item-5-title" style="display: block;">
      <div class="brevno">
        <label> 
     <img src="brevnoo.png" style="margin-left: 70px;">
      <br><input type="checkbox" name="Бревно">Бревно
      <br>Выберите необходимый диаметр
       <br><input type="checkbox">200мм
       <br><input type="checkbox">300мм
       <br><input type="checkbox">400мм
       <br><input type="checkbox">Свыше 400мм
  </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p><input class="send" type="submit" value="Далее"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="question hidden" id="question-5" style="display: block;">
    <div class="q-num">Вопрос 5 из 8</div>
    <div class="item-title item-6-title">Комплектация</div>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Сруб</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Сруб+фундамент</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Сруб+фундамент+кровля</label><br>
    <p><input class="send" type="submit" value="Далее"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="question hidden" id="question-6" style="display: block;">
    <div class="q-num">Вопрос 6 из 8</div>
    <div class="item-title item-6-title">Где находится объект?</div>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Новосибирск</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">10-50км</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">50-100км</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">100-500км</label><br>
    <p><input class="send" type="submit" value="Далее"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="question hidden" id="question-7" style="display: block;">
    <div class="q-num">Вопрос 7 из 8</div>
    <div class="item-title item-7-title">Когда планируется строительство?</div>
    <label><input type="checkbox">пока не планирую, интересует смета</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">В ближайший месяц</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">В ближайшеие полгода</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">В следующем году</label><br>
    <p><input class="send" type="submit" value="Далее"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="question hidden" id="question-8" style="display: block;">
    <div class="q-num">Вопрос 8 из 8</div>
    <div class="item-title item-8-title">В какой бюджет при строительстве планируете уложиться?</div>
    <label><input type="checkbox">до 1 000 000 рублей</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">от 1 000 000 до 2 000 000 рублей</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">от 3 000 000 до 4 000 000 рублей</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox">от 4 000 000 до 8 000 000 рублей</label><br>
    <p><input class="send" type="submit" value="Далее"></p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Не знаю, насколько это правильно, но что если в момент отправки формы поставить куку с каким-нибудь именем, а в момент загрузки страницы проверять, есть ли ли кука с таким именем, если есть ­— отображать форму, если нету — отображать текст.

Comment: "этаже страница" - зачем мудрить? Пусть это будет другая страница.

Comment: Как вариант тоже хороший. Тогда надо будет в скрипте прописать, что после завершения теста, должен перекидывать на созданную страницу. Правильно понимаю? Пока еще учусь только.